# Can I use Python instead of javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, web-development-server

I want to ask if I can use Python instead of Javascript I am interested in Python and I am a beginner-level web developer

I think maybe it is possible?

Comment: This question is very general and not really specific enough for SO. However, check out online material about Python web development, for example https://www.fullstackpython.com/web-development.html

Comment: It depends on what you want to use it for. If you want it to replace a backend written in JavaScript, such as one written in Node.js, then sure, you could use Python instead. But the special thing about JavaScript is that anyone's browser can run it. But Python doesn't work that way. So you can't replace the dynamic JavaScript that's on webpages itself. However you haven't actually been clear on what you want it for, so it's impossible to say if what you're asking for is feasible or not, without us knowing more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adil!
Why not? you can surely use python instead of JavaScript for web development. Python has libraries made for web development like django and flask.
Good luck Adil!!!

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can make web develop with python's web development libraries like django and flask.